# Centered Fixed Container

Tags: html, css

What I would like to do is to add position: fixed; to the following container but have it centered when compared to the header and footer

```
#OuterGallery {
      margin: -6px auto 0px auto;
      width: 960px;
      height: 675px;
      padding: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}
```

Here is the header code:

```
#HeaderBar {
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url(../image-core/header.png);
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 0px solid #FFF;
    position: absolute; z-index: 100;
}
```

it has been designed so that when you scroll down the header disappears

Finally hear is the footer

```
#Footer {
    background-color:transparent;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    display:none;
    z-index:10000;
    background-image: url(../image-core/footer.png);
    border-top: 5px solid #e0c495;
    -moz-box-shadow: -0px -1px 5px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -0px -1px 5px #000;
    box-shadow: -0px -1px 5px #000;
    background-color: #000;
    background-position: 0px 0px;
    height: 35px;
```

Thank you very much for the help you can provide

Comment: `#OuterGallery {position:fixed; top:80px; bottom:35px; width:100%;}` I think

Comment: that works but the scroll function stopped working. I tried height: 100%; overflow-y: scroll; but the scrolling does not work

Comment: correction: Works in IE but the scrollbar is disabled in Chrome

Comment: let me guesst. The contents of `OuterGallery` take more place then it's height? If so, then set `overflow:auto;` for `#OuterGallery`. But I think this is a wrong approach from the start.